# How to calculate different prices

Tags: android

I know that this is a small and stupid question but, although I am not completely beginner in Java, I am still in beginning on my learning path. 
I am making an app where the user can buy books. First, all prices books had the same prices and then my "customer" said that he would like to change some prices, and messed my workflow, my logic and my code.... 
How to change that.

When user clicks some book he will able to fill up form. In that form, he will find a field with quantity.The app will automatically calculate the end price. 
I do not have a problem only with code...but I can not wrap my head around it.
usually I do pseudo code so that I can "visualize" my code but in this case I can't.I do not know why this is so hard...because probably solution is shamefully easy.

This is my first book activity. There is seven. Price of this book is 100

```
     public class PrvaKnjiga extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.knjiga);

            PDFView pdfView  = (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
            pdfView.fromAsset("loops.pdf").load();
            pdfView.enableSwipe(true);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.myFAB);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent prvaKnjigaIntent = new Intent(PrvaKnjiga.this, Narudzbina.class);
                    startActivity(prvaKnjigaIntent);
                }
            });
            FloatingActionButton fabKontakt = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myFAB_kontakt);
            fabKontakt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+1111111111"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(PrvaKnjiga.this, "Radi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            });
        }

        }
```

Here is my "Order" activity.Here i am calculating price.Here is price of the first book of 100. But what to do with other prices?

```
    public class Narudzbina extends AppCompatActivity {

   String porukaGreska="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.narudzbina);
    }

    public void kreiranjeNarudzbine(View v) {
        EditText editTextIme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ime);
        String imeNarucioca = editTextIme.getText().toString();
        editTextIme.setText(StringUtils.capitalize(imeNarucioca.toLowerCase().trim()));


        EditText editTextPrezime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prezime);
        String prezimeNarucioca = editTextPrezime.getText().toString();
        editTextPrezime.setText(StringUtils.capitalize(prezimeNarucioca.toLowerCase().trim()));

        EditText editTelefonNarucioca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefon);
        String telefonNarucioca = editTelefonNarucioca.getText().toString();


        EditText editAdresaNarucioca = (EditText) findViewById(adresa);
        String adresaNarucioca = editAdresaNarucioca.getText().toString();
        editAdresaNarucioca.setText(StringUtils.capitalize(adresaNarucioca.toLowerCase().trim()));


        EditText editGradNarucioca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grad);
        String gradNarucioca = editGradNarucioca.getText().toString();
        editGradNarucioca.setText(StringUtils.capitalize(gradNarucioca.toLowerCase().trim()));


        EditText editKolicina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kolicina_narucena);
        String narucenaKolicina = editKolicina.getText().toString();
       //  int kolicina = Integer.parseInt(narucenaKolicina);
        int kolicina = 0;
        try {
            kolicina = Integer.parseInt(narucenaKolicina);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            narucenaKolicina = "";
        }

        int cenaNarudzbine = cena(kolicina);

        String poruka = sumiranjeNarudzbine(imeNarucioca, prezimeNarucioca, telefonNarucioca, adresaNarucioca, gradNarucioca, cenaNarudzbine);
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", "+111111111");
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", poruka);

        if(imeNarucioca!=null && imeNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Unesite ime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(prezimeNarucioca!=null && prezimeNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this,"Unesite Prezime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else if(telefonNarucioca!=null && telefonNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this,"Unesite kontakt telefon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(adresaNarucioca!=null && adresaNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this,"Unesite adresu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(gradNarucioca!=null && gradNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Navedite grad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (narucenaKolicina != null && narucenaKolicina.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Navedite zeljenu kolicinu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
    }

    private int cena(int kolicina){
        int cenaKnjige = 100;
        cenaKnjige = kolicina * cenaKnjige;
        return cenaKnjige;
    }

    private String sumiranjeNarudzbine(String imeNarucioca, String prezimeNarucioca, String telefonNarucioca,String adresaNarucioca,String gradNarucioca,int cenaNarudzbine) {
        String poruka = "Ime: " + imeNarucioca;
        poruka = poruka + "\n" + "Prezime: " + prezimeNarucioca;
        poruka = poruka + "\n" + "Broj Telefona: " + telefonNarucioca ;
        poruka = poruka + "\n" + "Adresa Nrucioca: " + adresaNarucioca;
        poruka = poruka + "\n" + "Grad: " + gradNarucioca;
        poruka = poruka + "\n" + "Cena: " + cenaNarudzbine;
        return poruka;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand where you are having problem. I already have done everything. You just have the user o show a popup on click of a book, in which you will be having two edit texts; one for price and other for quantity. And when user types you have to get the values from edit texts, and call the method "cena()", but you have to add an other parameter in arguments for price. You have to add a "submit/done" button in the popup as well, then you have to call the method "cena()" and pass the value of price and quantity. It'll calculate with your old logic. one more thing you have to replace the value of variable "cenaKnjige" with the value of price that user has typed.
I guess you are just tired right now, It happens sometimes. Take some rest and come back to the code and you'll be able to resolve it.